# CSS file won't update in CentOS7

Tags: css, apache, centos, centos7, httpd.conf

I recently switched my web hosting to CentOS7 dedicated server. I uploaded JS, CSS, HTML files and they worked just fine but when I uploaded a latest version of .html and .css, the html file did update but for some reason .css remained the same. To make sure I visit domain.com/css/style.css and search for the new styles but they were not there. Also I've cache enabled and I did clear my browser cache and restart httpd/apache in my CentOS server.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was mod_pagespeed saving site's cache. Delete them from /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/* and /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/v3/*